Boltzmann distribution and sigmoid
This question is probably too simple, and I am embarrassed to ask it, but I don't get what is the relation between the sigmoid functction:
$f(e) = 1/(1+\exp(-e/t))$
and the Boltzmann-Gibbs distribution $b(e) = \exp(-e/t)/Z$. In the context of machine learning they'd better be the same or similar.
Motivation: I know that Boltzmann machine (BM) is named this way because it capitalizes on collecting Boltzmann statistics off an input data set. Hence, the underlying distribution is better to be Boltzmann-Gibbs, but it is actually sigmoid. However, BM is developed for binary elements $\{0,1\}$, while Boltzmann distribution is usually expressed for $\{-1,1\}$, hence, spins in Ising model sense. I suspect, if I start from Boltzmann-Gibbs distribution and transform variables from the domain $\{-1,1\}$ to $\{0, 1\}$, I should be able to recover the sigmoid. Is that true?

It is explained in the section Unit State Probability: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_machine

@Syrocco Thanks! Now I am confused why in conventional MCMC the update rule is not sigmoid, but $\exp(-\Delta E/T)$

For the MCMC the update rule is the ratio of probability. And indeed, the ratio of the sigmoids in a simple double state system is $e^{-\Delta E/T}$! Taking back the notation of the article I linked: $P_{on} = \dfrac{1}{1+e^{-\Delta E/T}}$, since we are in a double state situation: $P_{off} = 1-P_{on}$ and the acceptance rate for a MCMC step (on->off, the only one possible here) is $P_{off}/P_{on}=\dfrac{1-P_{on}}{P_{on}}=e^{-\Delta E/T}$ which follows from the sigmoid probability distribution

FWIW, I don't know much about machine learning or statistical inference, but in statistical mechanics, the sigmoid appears when you have a two level system (Fermi distribution). So you really have to think of it (I think) as a function that deals with binary states/data.

Yeah, right, but {0,1} vs {-1,1} are two (supposedly) equivalent representations of a two-level system. In case with {0,1}, however, if var = 0, the whole term goes away from E(var) => read "I only care about activation, not inhibition" => sigmoid. For {-1,1} var = -1 contributes, hence, logical "False" carries information as well as "True" => Boltzmann. These seem to put MCMC using pure Boltzmann, and Boltzmann Machine using sigmoid to exactly right correspondence, except, Fermi-Dirac is applied to {-1,1} fermionic basis...
